# Do pairs of numbers that have common factors over 1 have more common multiples than pairs that don't?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

Here's a (perhaps messy) formalisation of my problem. I'm not sure if it works, but I'd be glad to explain it further.

Take four integers $a,b,c,d$.
Suppose $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(c,d)>1$.
For some limit $\ell$, let $M_{\ell,a,b}$ be the set of common multiples of $a$ and $b$ smaller than $\ell$, i.e. $M_{\ell,a,b} = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m  < \ell, a|m, b|m \}$.

My hypothesis is: if $\ell$ is large enough, $a$ and $b$ will have more common multiples if they have a common factor over 1, than if they don't have one. In other words, for some $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(c,d)>1$, then $|M_{\ell,a,b}| > |M_{\ell,c,d}|$ is always true.

Is my hypothesis correct? How do I prove it? Can it be generalised to larger sets of numbers (e.g. what if we compare sets of three numbers)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Let gcd(a,b) and lcm(a,b) denote the greatest common divisor of $~a,b~$ and least common multiple of $~a,b~$ respectively.  Then, from basic number theory : $$\text{lcm}(a,b) ~=~ \frac{a \times b}{\text{gcd}(a,b)},$$ and, given any common multiple $~M~$ of $~a,b~$ you have that $$\text{lcm}(a,b) ~~\text{divides}~~M.$$

Comment: One way of verifying the two assertions in the previous comment is by focusing on the fact that for any positive integer $~n \geq 2,~$ you have that $~n~$ has a unique prime factorization.

Comment: If $M_{\ell,a,b} = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m  < \ell, a|m, b|m \}$, is the claim that  for any $a,b,c,d$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(c,d)>1$, there exists $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|M_{\ell,c,d}|>|M_{\ell,a,b}|$? Or something else?

Comment: @Sil Yes, that's right! I've updated the wording in the original question.

Comment: @user2661923 I understand your assertions, but I'm not sure how they answer my question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Since multiples of the $a$ and $b$ are the same set as multiples of $lcm(a,b)$, we have that for large $l$, $|M_{a,b,l}|\sim l/lcm(a,b) =gcd(a,b)l/(ab)$. Thus, for small changes of a, b, l the number of multiples is approximately proportional to the gcd.

Comment: It’s not true for all a,b,c,d. I.e. consider if a,b=1,2 and c,d= 1000,2000. Then the first group has gcd 1 but will have half of all numbers which is way more than the second group which has a gcd of 1000.